# Why fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 0) use in serial port programming

Tags: c, linux, serial-port, fcntl

I am starting serial port programming in Linux. After reading several examples on the web, I don't understand exact effect of `fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 0)`? It is clearing bits, but what flags does it affect? What does it set and or clear?

Comment: [read this first, please](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fcntl).

Answer (score 5):

Take one by one

1) Function call used

`fcntl()` - It perform the operation on file descriptor passed in argument.

2) 2nd argument in call

[F_SETFL](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fcntl) (int)

> Set the file status flags to the value specified by arg. File access
>   mode (O_RDONLY, O_WRONLY, O_RDWR) and file creation flags (i.e.,
>   O_CREAT, O_EXCL, O_NOCTTY, O_TRUNC) in arg are ignored. On Linux this
>   command can change only the O_APPEND, O_ASYNC, O_DIRECT, O_NOATIME,
>   and O_NONBLOCK flags.

3) 3rd argument in call

It is 0 means, It set [file status flag](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/File-Status-Flags.html#File-Status-Flags) to zero. 
As Jean-Baptiste Yunès said in comment.

> file access mode and file creation flags are ignored. This command
>   reset every other flags: no append, no async, no direct, no atime, and
>   no nonblocking

---

So finally

```
fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 0)
```

This call will set opened file desciptor's `file status` flag to value 0.

---

But idealy this way we should not change file status flag. 
Best way is to first get the current file status flag using `F_GETFL` and then just change required bit in that. 
See example:

If you want to modify the file status flags, you should get the current flags with F_GETFL and modify the value. Don’t assume that the flags listed here are the only ones that are implemented; your program may be run years from now and more flags may exist then. For example, here is a function to set or clear the flag O_NONBLOCK without altering any other flags:

```
/* Set the O_NONBLOCK flag of desc if value is nonzero,
   or clear the flag if value is 0.
   Return 0 on success, or -1 on error with errno set. */

int
set_nonblock_flag (int desc, int value)
{
  int oldflags = fcntl (desc, F_GETFL, 0);
  /* If reading the flags failed, return error indication now. */
  if (oldflags == -1)
    return -1;
  /* Set just the flag we want to set. */
  if (value != 0)
    oldflags |= O_NONBLOCK;
  else
    oldflags &= ~O_NONBLOCK;
  /* Store modified flag word in the descriptor. */
  return fcntl (desc, F_SETFL, oldflags);
}
```

Comment: Wrong, **file access mode and file creation flags** are ignored. This command reset every other flags: no append, no async, no direct, no atime, and no nonblocking.

Comment: @Jigar patel - Thank you very much for the clear answer

Comment: I think `value` should be made `bool`. I know, very new-sk00l but ... better than a whole `int`.

Comment: @msc Thanks in stackoveflow is Upvote and Accepting answer. Anyway happy coding

Answer (score 0):

per the man page for fcntl()

> F_SETFL (int)
>
> Set the file status flags to the value specified by arg.  File
>                 access mode (O_RDONLY, O_WRONLY, O_RDWR) and file creation
>                 flags (i.e., O_CREAT, O_EXCL, O_NOCTTY, O_TRUNC) in arg are
>                 ignored.  On Linux this command can change only the O_APPEND,
>                 O_ASYNC, O_DIRECT, O_NOATIME, and O_NONBLOCK flags.  It is not
>                 possible to change the O_DSYNC and O_SYNC flags; see BUGS,
>                 below.

This is from the [*man* page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html).

Comment: Please, when downvoting some answer, explain at least the reasons for the downvote, so people can improve their answers or edit them, so next time they don't get downvoted.